# New to Mono - help setting search path?

Tags: class, ide, mono, libraries

Running Ubuntu Oneric 11.10 with 1 GB RAM and 250 GB HDD Dell Inspiron Laptop.

I got some demo code from a tutorial to read XML. When I compile it, I get this message:

"The type or namespace name '.Xml' does not exist in the namespace 'System'. Are you missing an assembly reference?" (using System.Xml;)

I have the library in this path: /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Xml/4.0.0.0_b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll

Comment: I think you're trying to debug two separate problems here -- `monodoc` and `System.Xml`. Maybe pick which one you want fixed first?

Comment: Hello sarnold, Yes, I realized that while digging into this. I've edited the trouble report for the issue I'm really having. The other is a matter of getting a .png file and installing it into the path, I expect. Anyway, for my troubleshooting efforts, see comment below..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using MonoDevelop to build your application? If so, make sure that there is a reference to System.Xml in your project.
In case you are hardcore enough to "manually" use **dmcs** to build your application (or you are using a Makefile or some other automated build process), make sure you pass **/r:/usr/lib/mono/4.0/System.Xml.dll** as one of the arguments to your **dmcs** build command.

Only for didatic purposes, here is the references editing option in MonoDevelop, in which you should choose to add a reference:
[image: References editing menu in MonoDevelop]

- Note: your distro could have installed System.Xml.dll in another path, so please verify.
- Your monodoc problem is an entirely different issue and probably means either a directory or file is missing from the installed docs or there is a bug in monodoc entirely

Comment: Thanks Marcelo, and greetings; I have tried a number of things: export MONO_PATH=/usr/lib/mono/2.0:/usr/lib/mono/3.5:/usr/lib/mono/compat-2.0:/usr/lib/mono/4.0    Also edited the /usr/lib/mono-source-libs$ Options.cs file to include the System.Xml library (which I have as using System.Xml in my code), but no joy. If I get feed back stating this may be a bug, I'll report it, otherwise, I'll assume it is still my mistake, although I am at a loss for what to try next???

Comment: I don't see how any of your approaches will solve your problem. Again, are you using MonoDevelop? Just a using statement is not enough to successfully compile your project, you need a Project Reference to System.Xml.dll as well. If you read your error carefully, you'll see that the reference is the missing part.

Comment: Yes, I am using MonoDevelop, but I know nothing about the Project Reference you're talking about. I will look into it to see whether I can solve this. Thanks again!

Comment: I see. This really was a simple fix. I read about it here...http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/monodevelop-list/2006-October/004738.html Your hint on the terminology is what did the trick! Thanks.

Comment: @gvtmath glad you got it! I included an image for the purpose of clarification.

Comment: Please avoid editing your question's title to mark it as solved. Instead, accept an answer by clicking its check sign,

Comment: Thanks to everyone for all the input. I read some posts about other's not being able to find any libraries when editing the references as above, so I think my effort to export MONO_PATH was not entirely wasted.